# Rails routing short urls without controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, constraints

I am using [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for generating pretty urls.
I have single model, `Questionnaire`.
My routes look as follows:

```
              roi_summary_questionnaire GET        /questionnaires/:id/roi_summary(.:format)               questionnaires#roi_summary
lack_of_internal_controls_questionnaire GET        /questionnaires/:id/lack_of_internal_controls(.:format) questionnaires#lack_of_internal_controls
                         questionnaires POST       /questionnaires(.:format)                               questionnaires#create
                      new_questionnaire GET        /questionnaires/new(.:format)                           questionnaires#new
```

and links look like: `http://myapp/questionnaires/foo/roi_summary` where `foo` is a slug (company_name).

My goal is to get rid of of controller name in generated urls, that is: `http://myapp/foo/roi_summary`. My slugs are uniq.

What is the nicest way to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. The answer is as easy, as using `path` option:

```
resources :questionnaires, path: '' do
  ...
end
```

This is how you get rid of controller's name in url.